Second instance of Python application does not commit to MariaDB table
I have an application running on multiple Raspberry Pi's using Python 3.12.3 with all the latest updates and MariaDB 10.5.21 running on a separate dedicated Pi. The application retrieves UPS values at certain intervals and logs the values to a common table using a stored procedure.
Everything works as expected when run on a single Pi, but once it is running on more than one the first to start is the only one to log to the table. If I stop the first one, then restart the second, then that one will start logging and the first will not.
Below is the code I am using. DatabaseConnection() just returns a connection and the code snippet above it uses the connection. The autocommit=True in DatabaseConnection() is left over from before I added the explicit conn.commit(), but I was having the same issue before adding the commit and I assume an explicit commit will do no harm.
I come from a Windows/SQL Server/C# world and I'm just trying to transition as a hobby since I retired.
Any idea what would cause this behavior?
# Save the poll value to the database
conn = DatabaseConnection()
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("CALL ups_poll_ins(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",(ups.PiId, ups.SerialNo, ups.Status == 'ONLINE', ups.Load, ups.BatteryCharge, ups.TimeLeft, ups.TimeOnBattery))
conn.commit()
cur.close()
conn.close()`

def DatabaseConnection():
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.sections()
    config.read('/opt/database.ini')

    return mariadb.connect(
        host=config['DATABASE']['Host'],
        user=config['DATABASE']['User'],
        password = config['DATABASE']['Password'],
        database="home_monitoring",
        autocommit=True)


    ... CALL ups_poll_ins( ... )

You're calling a stored procedure to INSERT seven values.
We can't see the text of that procedure.
But the rest of the code is bog standard,
so the "stuck lock" trouble must be in there.
Prefer to INSERT seven values, instead of asking a procedure to do it for you.
Also, consider connecting to MariaDB via
sqlalchemy.
It lets you run same code on e.g. a local test sqlite DB,
which can be convenient for automated
test suites.
And it would hang onto a pool of cached DB connections for you.
The OP code appears overly eager to discard a perfectly good TCP connection.
We don't have a {connect, SELECT, INSERT} sequence,
so we don't see if queries would succeed when writes will hang.

It's possible to
view current locks,
for example with
show full processlist or
show engine innodb status.

I've looked for current locks and there are none displayed. I've also deliberately left out error handling so issues will not be hidden. It's almost like the database is set to single user, but since I'm opening and closing the connection I don't see how that could be the issue either.

Do the experiment: issue a plain old INSERT followed by COMMIT.

It turns out that the issue was not in the Python code at all, but in the stored procedure. There was logic in the procedure to update a count and date if the UPS values had not changed between calls rather than inserting a new log row. That logic worked fine for a single UPS since it was looking for the most recent date for the supplied UPS serial number, but was failing when the most recent row was not for the UPS the current call was being made for since I was missing the ID of the UPS in one of the procedure code blocks.
I caught it while I was pulling the procedure code apart to tray and convert it into a query string for testing. Thanks for J_H for sending me down that path.
